# How to hide a Label and show it when a button is pressed in AppleScript app?

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-objc

I would like to know how to hide/show a label using AppleScript I tried something like:

```
property label : missing value
    if label's isHidden() = 1
                label's setHidden_(0)
            end if
```

but mot working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an AppleScript `if` expression you have to coerce ObjC `BOOL` to AppleScript `boolean`.
But you can pass an AppleScript `boolean` in the setter.

```
if label's isHidden() as boolean then -- is true is redundant 
   label's setHidden:false
end if
```